# Copy directory and create upper directory structure

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

In windows (desktop, a batch file, xcopy, robocopy) is there a way to copy a directory and have the structure above it created on the destination?

For example,  say I have a directory of files at c:\data\outlook\profiles\2013.

I want to copy the 2013 directory to c:\copy but want it to look like this: c:\copy\data\outlook\profiles\2013.

Of course, I can manually create the structure before the copy, but I am looking to do this in bulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a routine that should copy the target with its full path.

```
@echo off
call :CopyWithPath "C:\Data\Outlook\Profiles\2013" "C:\Copy"
exit /b %ErrorLevel%

:CopyWithPath <Source> <Target>
md "%~f2\%~p1" && copy "%~f1" "%~f2\%~p1"
exit /b %ErrorLevel%
```

Example of the command with values

```
md "C:\Copy\Data\Outlook\Profiles\" && copy "C:\Data\Outlook\Profiles\2013" "C:\Copy\Data\Outlook\Profiles\"
```